# Read from a proprties file java

Tags: java

Im trying to read from a properties fie but its not working here is my code

```
File configFile = new File("intput.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
try
{
    FileReader read = new FileReader(configFile);

    if (income <= 11000)
    {
        tax = Double.parseDouble(prop.getProperty("tax", "0"));
        taxMessage.setText("Annual tax:" + tax);
    }
    read.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, but it doesn't display the output.

Comment: You are not getting any errors - because you catch and ignore them... put `printStacktrace` inside every `catch` - and see what the problem is....

Comment: When posting code you should take the time and format the code especially the indentation. How can you expect us to read such horrible formatted code?

Answer (score 0):

your properties has not been loaded. see [Properties#load(Reader)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-)

```
prop.load(read);
```

### Your code should be like this:

```
File configFile = new File("intput.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
try {
    FileReader read = new FileReader(configFile);
    prop.load(read);

    //the if block is not been executed when your income always > 11000 .
    if (income <= 11000) {
        tax = Double.parseDouble(prop.getProperty("tax", "0"));

        taxMessage.setText("Annual tax:" + tax);
    }
    read.close();
} catch (Exception ex) { throw new RuntimeException(ex); }
```

Comment: @rama :(,impossible， what your content of `input.properties`? is it contains a key `tax` in `input.properties`?

Comment: #input.Properties
tax=0
NI=0
tax1=0.20
NI1=0.12
tax2=0.40
NI2=0.2
tax3=0.45

Comment: @rama maybe you need to start with a small example. your `income` not read through `prop`.

Comment: I will do maybe its the codes placement or something.

Answer (score 0):

This below code can help. Either it is the location of the properties file or the load method causing you the problem.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {

            input = new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\intput.properties");

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

            // get the property value and print it out
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("tax"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```